# Theano running slowly

Tags: keras, theano

I implemented a 9 layer convolutional neural network in Keras (with Theano back end) and translated pre-trained weights from another network. But while it only takes less than 1s in the original network which is implemented in C, Theano takes like 10 seconds for a single image.

I am running on a 3 GB Quadro K4000 and has installed `cuda-repo-rhel7-7.5` and `cudnn-7.0-linux-x64-v3.0`. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Are you comparing like-for-like? Theano/Keras includes a compilation phase which may not be present in your previous implementation.

Comment: yes, in the C++ version, there's no compilation phase, can I speed up this compilation phase in Theano?

Comment: That sounds like a rather different question! Can you clarify: does your "10 seconds for a single image" include the compilation time?

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't know how to measure time excluding compilation time.

Comment: You can measure "excluding compilation time" by starting to time things after the first image is done. Keras also can be run with TensorFlow backend which has much faster compilation phase

Comment: Note that quicker compilation in TensorFlow can sometimes come at the expense of slower runtime after compilation. TensorFlow doesn't do automatic optimization to the same degree as Theano.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't use Tensorflow backend because the weight is transferred from a pre-trained model, and the dimension order in Tensorflow is somewhat wired and gives me a hard time to do reshape and dimension rearrangement. I will try to measure the "excluding compilation time". But in this way, theano might not be that practical. Because in my application, images will be processed one by one.

Comment: Is it possible to leave compilation phrase when deploying my model?

Comment: You only need to compile once then use the resulting function many times. No need to compile for each image.

Comment: Did you try to increase the batch size? It'll take advantage of the GPU's memory and might (in my case increased the training process) make it run faster

Comment: Yes, I increased the batch size to the largest batch size allowed by my GPU memory. I think it's meanly due to the compilation process. Thanks!